# Is it possible to verify existing Flutter/Dart publisher on pub.dev?

Tags: flutter, dart, pub.dev

I have created an account at `pub.dev` about a year ago using my `@gmail` account. Also, under that account I've created a new publisher using the domain that I own and the same `@gmail` email, but I didn't go through the verification process at that time. Is it possible now to verify that publisher's account?

I've tried searching, but all I could find are the answers related to verification of newly created accounts, not the existing ones.
Is it possible to delete an existing publisher (as it doesn't have any packages published) and go over the verification process again? Are there any other options?